# Rails model concept

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building an accommodation booking website on rails and I am confused about one aspect of the models. So normally the way I know of building it is by having a Room model that has many Reservations and the Reservation model belongs to the Room model. Problem is that this time I want the visitor to be able to book multiple rooms on one reservation. Is the Room has many Reservations association correct for that usage? Can anyone help me find a way of building that, do I have to use a single form that makes multiple records? I am sorry for my ignorance, it's the first time a concept like this fall into my hands.

Thank you all very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially need to have a many-to-many relationship defined and rails has a couple options to do so.

One option is the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, which you can read up on [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).  However, my preferred option is the `has_many, through: [model]` approach as such:

```
class Room
  has_many :room_reservations
  has_many :reservations, through: :room_reservations
end

class Reservation
  has_many :room_reservations
  has_many :rooms, through: :room_reservations
end

class RoomReservation
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :reservation
end
```

essentially you have an intermediate table to create the many-to-many join.

Comment: Thank you! You really helped me figure this out.